# saxon xpath 3.1 , access variables while creating map

Tags: saxon, oxygenxml, xpath-3.1

I have the following xml document:

```
<customers>
   <continent>NA</continent>
   <Type>Regular<Type>
   <customer>
      <name>John Smith</name>
      <address>123 Oak St.</address>
      <state>WA</state>
      <phone>(206) 123-4567</phone>
   </customer>
   <customer>
      <name>Zack Zwyker</name>
      <address>368 Elm St.</address>
      <state>WA</state>
      <phone>(206) 423-4537</phone>
   </customer>
<customers>
```

I am trying to construct a map for each customer as follows:

```
for $customer in //customers
return 
map {
'continent': //continent/string(),
'type': //Type/string(),
'name': $customer/name/string(),
'address': $customer/address/string(),
'state': $customer/state/string(),
'phone': $customer/phone/string()
}
```

but for each iteration i am using the same continent and type which are same for each customer.

how can i construct my xpath so that the continent and type elements are generated only once, and can be accessed in each map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended `for $customer in //customer` (not `//customers`).

The Saxon-EE optimizer will automatically pull the expressions `//continent/string()` and `//Type/string()` out of the "for" loop, but if you want to do this optimization manually you can write:

```
let $continent := //continent/string(), $type := //Type/string()
return
  for $customer in //customers
  return 
    map {
     'continent': $continent,
     'type': $type,
     'name': $customer/name/string(),
     'address': $customer/address/string(),
     'state': $customer/state/string(),
     'phone': $customer/phone/string()
   }
```

Alternatively, I would probably write this without any variables as

```
(//customer) !
    map {
     'continent': string(..!continent),
     'type': string(..!type),
     'name': string(name),
     'address': string(address),
     'state': string(state),
     'phone': string(phone)
   }
```

Comment: Dr. Kay, I think the OP wants to store a "reference" to the common values -- not the values themselves. I showed how to do this in the second variant of my answer

Answer (score 0):

> but for each iteration i am using the same continent and type which
>   are same for each customer.
>
> how can i construct my xpath so that the continent and type elements
>   are generated only once, and can be accessed in each map.

**I would first create another `map` and assign it to a variable**:

```
let $common := map
{
 'continent' : /customers/continent/string(.),
 'type' : /customers/Type/string(.)
}
 return
  for $customer in /customers/customer
  return 
    map {
     'continent': $common?continent,
     'type': $common?type,
     'name': $customer/name/string(),
     'address': $customer/address/string(),
     'state': $customer/state/string(),
     'phone': $customer/phone/string()
   }
```

**Or one can even just store `$common` in each map** -- this means that whenever `continent` or `type` are needed from any map (let's say contained in a variable `$theMap`), these will be accessed as:

```
$theMap?common?continent
```

and

```
$theMap?common?type
```

**If this design is preferrable to you, then the code to generate the maps will be**:

```
let $common := map
{
 'continent' : /customers/continent/string(.),
 'type' : /customers/Type/string(.)
}
 return
  for $customer in /customers/customer
  return 
    map {
     'common': $common,
     'name': $customer/name/string(),
     'address': $customer/address/string(),
     'state': $customer/state/string(),
     'phone': $customer/phone/string()
   }
```